# [Jar][Android P] How to build a jar library into /vendor/framework

Tags: android, frameworks, android-source

In Android souce code (AOSP), I am trying to compile a jar library into **/vendor/framework/** but not **/system/framework**.

So I did the change in Android.bp for this library:

```
java_library {
    name: "com.test.provider",
    srcs: ["./java/**/*.java"],
    vendor: true,
    dex_preopt: {
        app_image: true,
    },
}
```

The com.test.provider.jar was built to **/vendor/framework/** now.

Then I use this library in SystemUI, did the change in frame/base/packages/SystemUI/Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES += com.test.provider
```

And also refer the class that defined in com.test.provider.jar, SystemUI was built successful.

But when this APP was running, got the below error message:

```
12-27 11:35:41.807  5449  5449 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-27 11:35:41.807  5449  5449 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.test.testprovidermanager.TestProviderManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/SystemUI/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Looks like OS seeks this library neither /system/framework nor /vendor/framework. But when I built this library to **/system/framework/**(Remove "vendor: true" from Android.bp), SystemUI works fine, it is so strange!

So my question is:
How to build a jar library to /vendor/framwork/ in Android P?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sloved this issue.
I forgot change permission in /system/etc/permission/testprovider_permission.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<permissions>
 <library name="com.test.provider"
      file="/system/framework/com.test.provider.jar"/>
</permissions>
```

Change **/system/framework/com.test.provider.jar** to **/vendor/framework/com.test.provider.jar**